# Dynamically Add tabPanel content which is list of cards to tabView in PrimeNg

Tags: primeng, angular8, tabview

I have to add tab content (primeng cards with content) dynamically into tabview using primeng in Angular 8. am trying with ComponentFactoryResolver to generate component dynamically . Please suggest best way to do.
i have attached image for reference.

```html
    <p-tabView class="ui-g-12 ui-g-nopad  ui-widget-content   ui-corner-all ui-no-border"  [activeIndex]="index" (onChange)="onProductSelect($event)" >
        <p-tabPanel #tabContent *ngFor="let product of productNames; let i = index;let first = first;" [selected]="first" [disabled]="isAllowedAccess"[enter link description here][1]
            [header]="'Profile ' + product.productName" lazy="true">  
    // <div>Content</div> tab content which is list of cards with content.here i have to add components dynamically   
        </p-tabPanel>
    </p-tabView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use an *ngFor inside the p-tabContent to render all the cards. This would be standardAngular and not related to primeNG

```
<div *ngFor="let mortgage of mortgages">
... render the content
</div>
```

What am I missing?